# How can I optimise this mysql query that includes a where clause with an epoch time range?

Tags: mysql, sqlperformance

I am trying to optimize the following mysql query:

```
SELECT events.id, events.tracking_id, events.event_time, events.event_type_id
FROM events
WHERE events.event_time >= 1564617600000000 AND events.event_time <= 1567295999000000
```

Here are the events table details:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `tracking_id` char(72) NOT NULL,
  `event_time` bigint(16) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `project_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `data_type_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `event_type_id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tracking_id`,`event_time`),
  KEY `id_idx` (`id`),
  KEY `server_id_idx` (`server_id`),
  KEY `event_type_id_idx` (`event_type_id`),
  KEY `event_time_idx` (`event_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

And the Explain output:

```
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+----------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys  | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+----------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | events | NULL       | ALL  | event_time_idx | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 2877592 |    37.48 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+----------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

The query takes about 30 seconds to run. And adding an index on event_time doesn't seem to have made any difference to the execution time - It doesn't look like the index is being used?

event_time was originally a char (36) but then I was getting the following warning: 'Cannot use range access on index 'event_time_idx' due to type or collation conversion on field 'event_time' which has dissappeared since I converted event_time to a bigint, but it's still not using the index.

What can I do to improve the performance of this query (which is actually a subquery in a much larger query)?

Comment: The index may be effectively used when the amount of rows filtered by the index is not above 5-7% of total rows amount. If the amount of filtered rows is greater then table scan is more effective. The only improvement which I see is in create covering index - the index which contains all 4 columns mentioned in the query with `event_time` column first. Server will scan the index and extract all values from it without accessing the table body.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for the suggestion. The covering index has cut the execution time down to around 20 seconds. However, I am still hoping to be able to optimise this query even further ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do all the rows in your table, or at least a majority of them, match the condition? In other words, the timestamps you give are from 2019-08-01 00:00:00 to 2019-08-31 23:59:59, so one full month. Are most of the rows currently in your table from this month?

MySQL does cost-based optimization. It estimates the cost of reading an index entry, then using that to look up a row. This means two lookups per index entry, plus some overhead.

MySQL is correct to estimate that a table-scan might be better than using an index in certain cases. The threshold is not documented, but in my experience if it estimates the number of matching rows are over 20% of the table, it tends to do a table-scan. *YMMV*

You can use an [index hint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html) to tell MySQL that it should treat a table-scan as infinitely costly, so if the index can be used at all, it should prefer it.

```
SELECT events.id, events.tracking_id, events.event_time, events.event_type_id
FROM events FORCE INDEX (event_time_idx)
WHERE events.event_time >= 1564617600000000 AND events.event_time <= 1567295999000000
```

But keep in mind MySQL's cost-based optimizer might have been right. It might in fact be less costly to do the table-scan, depending on your data.

Comment: In situations like in this question, should we also consider 1) hardware specs of server, 2) performance of same query in servers with different specs (say local, staging etc)

Comment: Indeed, the best way to know is for the OP to test with his data on his server.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for the insight. My query is returning ~647 thousand rows from a table of ~2.9 Million which is actually just slightly over your estimated threshold of 20%. When I drop the date range to a single day that returns just 24 thousand rows then the event_time_idx index does get used indeed and the query is much faster. Also if I try to force the index on the larger range then it performs worse. I understand the limitations better now. So thank you for your answer